# Sitemap Error General HTTP error: 404 not found

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I visit my webmaster tool and it shows the site map index error below.

what is problem my site map and how to solve this Problem?

please help.

[image]
How to fix this error

Comment: Wha's the url of your xml sitemap? Is it here when you open it with a browser?

Comment: bootcamplab.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Redirects to www.flagbootcamplab.com/sitemap.xml ... which then in my browser shows "server no found" (guessing dns error) - both things would separately explain why iy won't work for Google either

Comment: Any other options implementing code in app.py configuration file